# How to make log files rotate based on size using log4j.properties and also zipped

Tags: java, hadoop, ambari, log4j

subject - RollingFileAppender , and how to zip the rotated files

RollingfileAppender rotates log files based on file size. MaxFileSize indicates the maximum size of file while MaxBackupIndex indicates the amount of files to be kept in the log folder.

A sample property file is given below:

```
1   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileLogger
2   log4j.appender.fileLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
3   log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
4   log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
5   log4j.appender.fileLogger.File=example.log
6   log4j.appender.fileLogger.MaxFileSize=1KB
7   log4j.appender.fileLogger.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

Based on that configuration we can assume that logs will rotated as the follwing example

```
...Log.3
...Log.2
...Log.1
```

But they are not zipped !

My question is – based on sample property , 
what I need to change in my sample `log4j.properites` so files that rolled will be also **zipped**.

-

we configured the follwing ( according to Malte advice ) log4j for example but files that rotated are not zipped

note - this log4j is taken from Advanced hive-log4j from ambari

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}-.%i.log.zip
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=1KB
```

example of the logs files that we get ( as we can see files are not zipped )

```
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1055 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log.5
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1203 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log.4
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1098 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log.3
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1028 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log.2
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1239 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop       0 Aug 15 16:00 hiveserver2.log
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1065 Aug 15 16:00 hivemetastore.log.4
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1098 Aug 15 16:01 hivemetastore.log.3
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1120 Aug 15 16:01 hivemetastore.log.2
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop    1098 Aug 15 16:01 hivemetastore.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop     470 Aug 15 16:01 hivemetastore.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right configuration should be as the follwing ( already tested and verified )

```
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.DRFA.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  
log4j.appender.DRFA.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}.log
log4j.appender.DRFA.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}-.%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.DRFA.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
log4j.appender.DRFA.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=10
```

example of what we get under /var/log/hive

```
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 1019 Aug 15 20:13 hivemetastore.log-.2.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 1159 Aug 15 20:18 hiveserver2.log-.1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 5353 Aug 15 20:21 hiveserver2.log
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 1028 Aug 15 20:22 hivemetastore.log-.1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 2218 Aug 15 20:22 hivemetastore.log
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 4361 Aug 15 20:24 hiveserver2-report.json.tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 hive hadoop 4254 Aug 15 20:24 hivemetastore-report.json.tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

You should achieve a zipped file by using the file ending `.zip` convention.
See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies for more compression schemes.

```
log4j.appender.fileLogger.filePattern=%d{yyyyMMdd.HHmmss}.log.zip
```

or if you don't want a date but just a numbered log:

```
log4j.appender.fileLogger.filePattern=%i.log.zip
```

Comment: what is the filePattern=%I   ( I mean ? )

Comment: %i represents an integer counter. 
See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender in the documentation of the parameter `filePattern`.

Comment: see my update - we configured the follwing log4j for example but files that rotated are not zipped  , ( still files are not zipped )